# URL() constructor add %20 in host for chrome but its not valid in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, firefox, new-operator

I am using URL() constructor to check if URL is a valid one.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

If i run below code in chrome it added %20 after // in https:// s

```js
let url = new URL('https:// s');
console.log(url);
```

But in firefox or if i run this of code using node it throws an error.

Not why it behaving differently.
Is there any alternative for URL() constructor

Comment: Are you running Firefox 26 or higher? It is only supported in version 26 or higher.
Appart from that: Why do you want to have the space? Afaik, spaces in URL's are not allowed, so it is understandable that an error gets thrown.

Comment: Without looking at the specs I'd say Chrome is wrong. The purest implementation is paradoxically node's one, and they also do throw.

Comment: @SimonvanEndern i am using higher version of firefox. Ya spaces aren't allowed but i am confused why chrome is behaving in that why and adding %20 on its own

Comment: And what is the problem that Chrome does not throw an error? Knowing that, you could remove whitespace beforehand. Why does your URL start with whitespace? I would say as this is not a valid URL, the problem arises somewhere earlier in your software.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is buggy here, [the specs](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-basic-url-parser) state that

> 1. If url is not given:
>
>    1. Set url to a new URL.
>    2. If input contains any leading or trailing C0 control or space, validation error.

So this should be a validation error.

Unfortunately I don't know any other way to do the same (using an anchor exposes the same bug), maybe you could browserify [node's implementation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url), but I didn't try myself.